# In ASP.NET WebForms, what is the difference between <%:, <%=, and <%#?

Tags: webforms

This question is proving hard to google, so if there is a duplicate question & answer or definitive reference, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<% %>  An embedded code block is server code that executes during the page's render phase. The code in the block can execute programming statements and call functions in the current page class. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135(vs.80).aspx

<%= %> most useful for displaying single pieces of information. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx

<%# %> Data Binding Expression Syntax. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx

<%$ %> ASP.NET Expression. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

<%@ %> Directive Syntax. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e(VS.80).aspx

<%-- --%> Server-Side Comments. http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4acf8afk.aspx

<%: %> Like <%= %> But HtmlEncodes the output (new with Asp.Net 4). http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is actually described pretty well in msdn.
Check out following link:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)